# Access model in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5

I tried to access model TemporarySubject via my blade file. If the data exist in the model, my blade will show button red in colour else it shows a button with the default colour

Below are some of my code in blade. It seems like the code doesn't run into the @if @else condition because the output shows all button with red colour even the data do not exist in the model

```
@if ($rows->S4=='1')
  @if (App\TemporarySubject::where('subject_name','=','S4'))
   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-mini" title="Digital Logic">SCSR1013(S4)</button>
  @else
   <button class="btn btn-mini" title="Digital Logic">SCSR1013(S4)</button>
  @endif
@endif
```

The output should show the button in default colour because in temporary_subjects does not contain subject_name with 'S4' value, but it shows a red colour button instead. Hopefully, someone can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Pleeeeeeease don't use this kind of model queries inside your blade this kind of logic should be inside the controller or as method and passed to the view .. to maintain the MVC structure that laravel gives you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement always returns true as it is, hence the reason of seeing the red button always. You should change your condition to something like this:

```
App\TemporarySubject::where('subject_name', 'S4')->exists(); // default is = so no reason to add it again.
```

Just an extra tip: it will be better to share this condition through the controller instead.

Comment: sir, can u teach me how to make it in the controller and call it in blade? I'm new in laravel so didn't get it

Comment: You should go through the documentation, for start here is how you share something with the view from a route action: https://laravel.com/docs/master/views